# So, you're not allowed to copy data from foursquare's Venue Platform?

Tags: foursquare

I was reading the API policy of foursquare Venue Platform.

"You may not use the API to to add new places to your database or alter location details for places in your database."

It raised two questions to me:
1. How would they know, if one added new places, etc. to his/ her own database?

1. I hear that foursquare (used to) use the google maps api, to retrieve information for locations, so does that mean it is viable to use Google Map's data to create one's own basic database?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a very interesting topic. Have  you found a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically they are telling you - you can use our API and database to create great apps, but do not steal our know-how(the database copy). They won't probably find out if you copy few of them, but say - you make a startup based on their database which you fully copied, then they can sue you and get you in trouble....

For Google usage, refer to Google Policy [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt reply, Michal. But still, what if I start up with a OSM database, and then I can ...hm augment it with new data piece by piece? No?